# Linux CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT for a quad core ARM A53 (newbie doubts)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, xilinx, preemption

I would like to activate the PREEMPTion features of my Linux Kernel. To do that I should download the right patch matching the version of the kernel I am using and that I compiled (as explained [here](https://wiki.trenz-electronic.de/display/PD/How+to+install+the+linux-rt+%28Real-Time%29+patch)). The version of the kernel I have is the **Linux version 4.9.0** (obtained just typing `uname -a` from the command line and double checked in `/proc/version`.

In the [linux kernel](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.9/) page (where is possible to download the patch for this purpose) I cannot find the exact matching version that I am using. Which one should I use?

Also, if you have some suggestion on how to do it properly it will be appreciated!

The other question I have is: can I continue to use the same application I have developed observing, when possible, the improvement or degradation of performance? And what about the driver I was developing? or third parts device-driver?

**UPDATE:**

- I am using a Xilinx Zynq Ultrascale+ equipped with a quad core ARM 53. The board used is the zcu102 by Xilinx.
- The source files of the kernel come from [here](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx) and the file system is Linaro

Comment: https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx and the file system is Linaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can check folder "older" ( https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.9/older/ ) - there you can find files patch-4.9-rt1.patch.gz and patches-4.9-rt1.tar.gz
2. Note, that current version in github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx is 4.14. Are you sure, that you have correct source code?

Comment: yes, I did it yesterday and it works (of course I am sure about the version).! Thank you Roman!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the information about how to install PREEMPT_RT on ZCU102 using Petalinux 2019.1:

1. Download and install Petalinux 2019.1 from [the Xilinx website](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/embedded-design-tools.html)
2. Download ZCU102 BSP 2019.1 from [the Xilinx website](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/embedded-design-tools.html)
3. Create a project: `petalinux-create -t project -s xilinx-zcu102-v2019.1-final.bsp`
4. Unzip the PREEMPT_RT patch http://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.19/older/patch-4.19-rt1.patch.gz onto the **project-spec/meta-user/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx/** directory
5. Edit the file **project-spec/meta-user/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_%.bbappend** and append

   ```
   SRC_URI_append = " file://patch-4.19-rt1.patch"
   ```
6. Make sure the priority for the meta-user layer is 7 in the project file **project-spec/meta-user/conf/layer.conf**
7. Configure th project: `petalinux-config`
8. Configure the kernel enabling full preemptive support: `petalinux-config -c kernel`
9. Build: `petalinux-build`
10. Generate the BOOT.BIN file: `petalinux-package --boot --fsbl images/linux/zynq_fsbl.elf --u-boot images/linux/u-boot.elf`

Comment: +1 thank you! these are the right steps when using petalinux. However, I was compiling and executing all the steps manually when I first tried it (a couple of year ago I guess)